# Android Google Map - Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to show `GoogleMap` on my `Activity`. I have done all necessary steps including key generation, linked `google-play-services_lib`, added `android-support-v4.jar`. But I am facing an error because of `Fragment`. I have tried many solutions, spent many hours but unable to solve this problem. Please help me.

**MapActivity.java**

```
package com.example.classified_android_app;

import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }
}
```

**map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="17.660324"
        map:cameraTargetLng="75.906601"
        map:cameraZoom="15" >
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.classified_android_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.classified_android_app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.classified_android_app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="Google Map"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Log**

```
06-21 09:54:08.592: W/dalvikvm(13704): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4191d908)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.classified_android_app/com.example.classified_android_app.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-21 09:54:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(13704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Your   `android:minSdkVersion="16"` so you should use `MapFragment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is your `android:minSdkVersion="16"`

> What original docs said is

If your `android:minSdkVersion > 12` then you should use `MapFragment` with extends `Activity`

And

If your`android:minSdkVersion < 12` then you should use `SupportMapFragment` with extends `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="17.660324"
        map:cameraTargetLng="75.906601"
        map:cameraZoom="15" >
    </fragment>
```

with

```
<fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="17.660324"
        map:cameraTargetLng="75.906601"
        map:cameraZoom="15" >
    </fragment>
```

See this link provided by android official website [How to add static fragment from XML](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.classified_android_app/com.example.classified_android_app.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your onCreate().

```
       SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and replace this.

```
<fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="17.660324"
        map:cameraTargetLng="75.906601"
        map:cameraZoom="15" >
    </fragment>
```

with

```
<fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        map:cameraTargetLat="17.660324"
        map:cameraTargetLng="75.906601"
        map:cameraZoom="15" >
    </fragment>
```

Comment: When I add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in fragment, then it is showing this error - Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment

Comment: Should work the way you had that as long as you add the SupportMapFragment to your onCreate()